# Getting started writing Extensions/Add-Ons/Plugins/BHOs for IE

Tags: internet-explorer, browser-extension

It seems as if Microsoft has abandoned the idea of writing extensions (or plugins, or BHOs, or whatever it's call now) for IE.  I can't seem of find any documentation on the topic that's less than 5 or 6 years old.  Is this even a thing anymore?  I've written one for Chrome that I'd love to duplicate in IE, but it seems hunting down documentation on this is near impossible.

All I really expect to do with the thing is modify the CSS/HTML of a site visited by the user to add a few niceties.  This is a cinch in Chrome, but I don't know where to begin in IE.

Comment: The documentation sucks, but BHOs are indeed still the way to go for IE (even 11). How are your C++ skills? (use C++, not C# for performance reasons).

Comment: They are enough for this, but I'm not willing to use C++ for a browser extension.  I suppose I'm just going to stick with Chrome.